# Allow users to create tables, but not drop them in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, permissions, privileges

By default, PostgreSQL allows the owner and any `SUPERUSER` roles to drop tables. We're trying to create a role that can create tables in a schema, but not drop them once they're created.

More ideally, we'd actually like the created tables to be owned by `postgres`.

Is there any way to force created tables in a schema to automatically be owned by `postgres`, or at least prevent them from being dropped by the owner? We are using PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: This may be a bit of a kluge, but can you create a function that will create the table and pass the DDL to the function?  Something like `create function create_table(table_schema text, table_name text, table_ddl)`

Comment: Clever! But I'd never be able to get them to go for that.